# Hibernate 6.1.7.FINAL ignoring discriminator column on insertion

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

After the migration of my project from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3 and updating the hibernate version to 6.1.7.Final, I'm encountering some problems with something that worked before.

Hibernate seems to ignore the insertion of the discriminator value on creation.

Example:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = Book.BOOK_TABLE_NAME)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Book {

    public static final String IDBOOK = "IDBOOK";
    public static final String BOOK_TABLE_NAME = "BOOK";

    @Id
    @Column(name = IDBOOK)
    private Long id;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;

    ....
}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
@DiscriminatorValue("PERIODIC")
@Table(name = "PERIODIC")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDPERIODIC")
public class Periodic extends Book {

    ...attributes
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
@DiscriminatorValue("CODE")
@Table(name = "CODE")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDCODE")
public class Code extends Book {

    ...attributes
}
```

After executing the create method on the BookRepository and inspecting the generated code by hibernate, I found out that is not adding the type value:

```
insert
    into
        book
        (*"...many values except type"*, idbook)
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        periodic
        (... idperiodic)
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The result of this insert is the column type being empty in the database.

What may be the issue?

Comment: I would try to remove the field `type` from the entity `Book`. This column will be managed by Hibernate as a discriminator. In your case the column is annotated as `insertable=false`. This can cause the issue. (Not tested yet. Hope it helps)

Comment: From Javadoc of Column insertable attribute: _Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provider_

Comment: So I removed the insertable = false in the attribute and now is trying to insert it but is not automatically detecting the type instead it waits for me to set it manually ex ->
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "type" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Also tried completely removing the attribute type from the class definition and it does not work either.

Comment: I have reproduced your settings. Everything works as expected. The type column is managed and populated correctly. As your code has been migrated there is probably a version mix. Please share your pom.xml or gradle file. Please also check if you have anywhere in your code an import javax.persistence? It should NOT be the case. Only jakarta.persistence is valid for Hibernate 6

Comment: I have tested with Spring Boot 3.1.1 which incudes Hibernate 6.2.5.Final

Comment: Did you have to remove the insertable = false, updatable = false  for it to work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254390/discussion-between-mar-z-and-cesar-castro-aroche).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem with @DiscriminatorColumn when I upgraded to Spring Boot 3.

However, in [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) 5, I didn't have the `type` column; I had to add it.
I'm using **hibernate-core 6.2.13**, what came with **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 3.1.5**.

Maybe try to delete the strict Hibernate dependency in your [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) file and use Hibernate which comes along with Spring Boot.

Comment: Re *"Spring 3"*: Do you mean *"Spring Boot 3"*? (Two instances)

Comment: How does a POM come into the picture?

Comment: Due to my problems with migrating to Spring Boot 3, I meant that there is no harm with trying to use another version of Hibernate. It's not solution, it's only suggestion that might help